# Facebook Graph Api: using limit with since and until

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to use limit along with since and until in Graph Api call. In between a certain time interval, I have 2 uploaded photos. The query looks like this:

```
me/photos/uploaded?since=2009-12-31T18%3A30%3A00.000Z&until=2010-12-31T18%3A30%3A00.000Z&limit=200
```

This query has limit set as 200 , and it correctly returns the 2 photos. But the problem arises when I have a smaller value of limit, lets say 100. So basically a query:

```
me/photos/uploaded?since=2009-12-31T18%3A30%3A00.000Z&until=2010-12-31T18%3A30%3A00.000Z&limit=100
```

return me an empty json. Even though there are only two photos, a limit of 100 returns null. Any insights?

Comment: Is this album contains other private photos? Because the total of response object fewer than limit is expected behavior as explained at https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/478/.

Comment: I am aware of this blog post. No, there are no private photos. Anyways, these photos are the same user's photos and not their friend's photos, so even if they are private, it should not be an issue.

Comment: Anyways, I found the reason for this strange behaviour. The filter limit is applied first and then other filters like since and until are applied. Since data returned is in decreasing order of created date, my filters containing older dates will return null if the limit is very less, that is those first few will not belong to the older days. So, that is why , I get correct results when the limit is huge.